# Mysql comparing user's data to database data

Tags: php, mysql, email, session

I am developing a registration form with validation and I have a database using mysql. And I want to compare the user's entered data to the data's in the database specially the email to check if it's already listed/used in the database. I have made an alert code if the user enters less than 6 characters for the password and I want to do the same for the email address if it is already existing in my database. Here is my code:

Form Code:

```
 <?php
//Start session
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Athan Motorcycle Spare Parts and Accesories</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{

var a=document.forms["abc"]["firstname"].value;
var b=document.forms["abc"]["lastname"].value;
var d=document.forms["abc"]["email"].value;
var e=document.forms["abc"]["pword"].value;
var f=document.forms["abc"]["ambot"].value;
var g=document.forms["abc"]["number"].value;
var h=document.forms["abc"]["house"].value;
var i=document.forms["abc"]["street"].value;
var j=document.forms["abc"]["city"].value;
if ((a==null || a==""))
{
 alert("you must enter your username");
 return false;
 }
if ((b==null || b==""))
 {
 alert("you must enter your password");
 return false;
 }
 if ((d==null || d==""))
 {
  alert("you must enter your email address");
 return false;
  }
 if ((e==null || e==""))
 {
  alert("you must enter your password");
  return false;
 }
 if ((f==null || f==""))
 {
 alert("Retype password");
 return false;
  }
 if ((g==null || g==""))
 {
 alert("you must enter your contact number");
 return false;
 }
 if ((h==null || h==""))
 {
 alert("you must enter your house location");
 return false;
 }
 if ((i==null || i==""))
  {
 alert("you must enter your Street");
 return false;
 }
 if ((j==0 || j==""))
  {
  alert("Please select your City");
  return false;
  }
 if( e != f ) {
 alert("Password does not match");
 return false;
 }
 var atpos=d.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=d.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=d.length)
 {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
 } 


 }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

  //called when key is pressed in textbox
$("#contact").keypress(function (e)  
{ 
  //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
  if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57))
  {
    //display error message
    $("#errmsg").html("Number Only").show().fadeOut("slow"); 
    return false;
  } 
});


  });
  </script>

  </script>



    </head>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src=”js/bootstrap.js”></script>

            <div class="container well">
            <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
            <li><img src="img/12.jpg"></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="customization.html">Customization</a></li>
            <li><a href="error.php">Order Parts</a></li>
            <li><a href="inspiration.html">Inspiration Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="loginuser.php">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-unit">


<!-- Skitter Styles -->
<link href="css/skitter.styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Skitter JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.animate-colors-    min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"     src="js/jquery.skitter.min.js"></script>

<!-- Init Skitter -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({
            theme: 'clean',
            numbers_align: 'center',
            progressbar: true, 
            dots: true, 
            preview: true
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
 margin: 0; 
 }
 </style>

 <br>
<div style="width:400px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); -moz-box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); margin-top:20px; color:#FF0A0A;">
  <form id="form1" name="abc" method="post" action="addmem.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <div style="background-color:#cccccc; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; padding:5px; height:22px; width:390px;"> 


 <div style="float:left;"><strong>Members Registration</strong></div>
 <div style="float:right; margin-right:3px; background-color:#cccccc; width:25px; text-align:center; height:22px;"><a href="loginuser.php">X</a></div>


 </div>
 <table width="368" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2"><div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"><font color="white">All Field Mark with asterisk (<span class="style1"><b>*</b></span>) must be filled up</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000; font-size:12px;"><?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    echo '<ul class="err">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="120" valign="top"><div align="right"> <font color="#00EBFF">Firstname:    </div></td>
    <td width="236"><input type="text" name="firstname">
          <span class="style2">*</span></td>
  </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Lastname:</div>    </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname">
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Email:</div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email">
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Password:</div>    </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pword">
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Retype Password:</div></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="ambot">
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Contact Number:    </div></td>
            <td><input name="number" type="number" min="0" id="contact" size="11">
                  <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-    size:12px; color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold;" id="errmsg"></span><span class="style2">*    </span></td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Brgy. and House:    </div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="house">
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>

    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">Street No:</div>    </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="street">
        <span class="style2">*</span></td>
  </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="right"><font color="#00EBFF">City:</div></td>
            <td><select name="city"><option value="0">--Select One--</option>
                            <option value="Caloocan City">Caloocan City</option>
                            <option value="Las Pinas City">Las Pinas City</option>
                            <option value="Makati City">Makati City</option>
                            <option value="Malabon City">Malabon City</option>
                            <option value="Mandaluyong City">Mandaluyong City</option>
                            <option value="Manila">Manila</option>
                            <option value="Marikina City">Marikina City</option>
                            <option value="Muntinlupa City">Muntinlupa City</option>
                            <option value="Navotas">Navotas</option>
                            <option value="Paranaque City">Paranaque City</option>
                            <option value="Pasay City">Pasay City</option>
                            <option value="Pasig City">Pasig City</option>
                            <option value="Pateros">Pateros</option>
                            <option value="Quezon City">Quezon City</option>
                            <option value="San Juan">San Juan</option>
                            <option value="Taguig">Taguig</option>
                            <option value="Valenzuela City">Valenzuela City</option></select>
              <span class="style2">*</span></td>
          </tr>
   <tr>
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

 </form>
 </div>
 <hr>
                    <div class="footer">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Athan Motorcycle</p>
                    </div>



    </body>
 </html>
```

And here is my PHP code where i put the error:

```
<?php
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
include('config.php');


$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pword=$_POST['pword'];
$number=$_POST['number'];
$house=$_POST['house'];
$street=$_POST['street'];
$city=$_POST['city'];

$min_length = 6;  
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want  
 if(strlen($pword) >= $min_length){
 //this one will not feed in the database if there's a duplicate but still a problem ohmaygawd:3
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO athan_members (firstname, lastname, email, number, house1,     street1, city, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$number', '$house',     '$street', '$city', '$pword') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE")
mysql_query("INSERT INTO athan_members (firstname, lastname, email, number, house1,     street1, city, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$number', '$house',     '$street', '$city', '$pword')");
header("location: loginuser.php");
}
else
{
$errmsg_arr[] = 'password must contain not less than 6 characters';
$errflag = true;
}


if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: new.php");
        exit();
}




mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please use `PDO` or `mysqli`. `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: Where are you learning to do things this way? This is a super antiquated and massively error prone way of doing things. Using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) will make it a lot easier to get things done.

Comment: i'm just a super newbie sir @tadman and i'm just learning on my own way :3

Comment: There's nothing wrong with learning unless you're learning the wrong things. `mysql_query` is total junk and you shouldn't even be touching it, it's wickedly tricky to use correctly and is being removed from future versions of PHP because of how much trouble it causes. A modern framework will insulate you from these sorts of problems and give you a lot more reward for your learning time.

Comment: sir @tadman thank you for enlightening me. and now that i know in my self that i'm learning the hard/wrong way i will take your advice and use the development framework link you gave me. :)

Comment: oh my sir @tadman i really don't know that such thing exist and i'm really glad you let me know this. really appreciate it. you can put it in answer and i'm glad to accept it as the best answer for me. i'm really happy that i want to cry now because i'm so noob T_T

Comment: It's not really an answer, it's just a pointer. Getting a handle on a good development framework might seem like a lot of work, but the pay-off can be huge. As an example, if you use something like [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) you will be able to make use of [hundreds of add-on modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/) without having to do much more work. If you write from the ground up, you have to write everything yourself and repeat the mistakes other people have already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code to check whether a user with the given email already exists:

```
$result = mysql_query("select 1 from athan_members where email='"
                      . mysql_escape_string($email) . "'");
$userExists = (mysql_fetch_array($result) !== FALSE);
mysql_free_result($result);
```

After that, you can use the value stored in $userExists to do your error checking logic.

However, as other people stated, you shouldn't use mysql_ functions to work with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Query your database for entered email. If you got 0 rows, then it does not exist.